# Copy Files to task unable to locate **/*.ipa file

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Copy files task in Azure DevOps Pipelines produces an error when building cordova ios app. The build succeeds and when I check the sources directory I can locate the file but Copy Files task alwats fails to find the file. I am using a self hosted agent with system.debug variable set to true but cannot get any useful information from the log:

I have the following task configurations:

**Source Folder:**

$(Build.SourcesDirectory)

**Contents:**

**/*.ipa

**Target Folder:**

$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)

**Output:**

```
Unhandled: Failed find: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/ahmadkhudeish/build_agents/agent1/_work/1/s/platforms/ios/build/device/Patient List UAT.app'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Any help appreciated, thanks

Comment: from the output it seems your app having many whitespaces, `Patient List UAT.app` can you try to remove the white spaces and give it a try ?

Comment: @Jaydendran I have changed the name to trim whitespace but no luck. However, I have gotten around this issue by using a simple bash script to copy the file instead, I think the Copy Files task provided by Azure Pipelines is buggy and inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a bug in the copy files step:
https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/9046

Answer (score 0):

Try this, its working for me

```
task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: 'Bacpac'
    Contents: '**\*.bacpac'
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)'
```